# Retrieve a values from a different table in access vba

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, vba7

I have a form in access and the final price is the result of certain combinations. I attach the code and the values that I multiply are put in the code directly.

```
Option Compare Database


Private Sub BOLETA_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub CANTIDAD_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub CLINICA_LostFocus()
    If Me.CLINICA.Value = 400 Then
        If Me.EXAMEN.Value = 10 Then
            Me.PRECIO.Value = Me.CANTIDAD.Value * 45000
        End If
        If Me.EXAMEN.Value = 11 Then
            Me.PRECIO.Value = Me.CANTIDAD.Value * 30000
        End If
    End If
        
End Sub
```

I would like to put the prices in a table so that I can modify it whenever I want without having to touch the code. Is this possible? Thanks!!!!

Comment: Certainly. If you need to save these calculated results to different table, use SQL INSERT action or edit recordset. Common topic, many examples. When you have attempted code with issue, post question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time. Actually,  I don not need to save these calculated results to different table, These data are already saved in the main table. what I want is to be able to edit in a different table  the numbers by which are multiplied. The numbers are a price and it changes all the time. Tahnk you once more time!

Comment: You want the factors 45000 and 30000 to be dynamic instead of hard-coded? Yes, can put in a table then maybe use DLookup() in code to pull from table.

Comment: yes! but my experience en this is really low. I can´t find any example how "Dim" a new table working with another one. Even, I don{t know how to be able to reference the row and the colummn. Can you show me any example of that? Thank you once more time!

Comment: Build a table with fields Examen and Factor. Values for two records: 10 and 45000, 11 and 30000. `Me.PRECIO = Me.CANTIDAD * DLookup("Factor","tblFactors","Examen=" & Me.Examen)`. Now whenever you change Factor in table, the code will pull most current value. Another approach would join tables on the Examen fields. This is really basic relational database functionality.